# How do I count occurrences of distinct data in two columns from 1 table MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to count the number of occurrences of people from two columns in one table, and return the amount of times they show up in both columns as a single number

```
inputs 
person1 person2
person2 person3
person3 person4
person4 person2

output
person1 1
person2 3
person3 2
person4 2
```

This is what I have so far, though it just returns the names and counts of the first character.

```
SELECT firstname, COUNT(firstname + secondname) FROM meeting GROUP BY firstname;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*)
FROM ( SELECT firstname name
       FROM meeting 
       UNION ALL
       SELECT secondname
       FROM meeting ) x
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: name/firstname confusion.

Comment: Just as a quick note, MySQL required me to name the sub-query with an as statement.  
You're a beautiful human being and I love you greatly. Embarrassing to say but I was stuck on this problem for over 5 hours. Thank you.

Comment: @BenGarcia *MySQL required me to name the sub-query with an as statement.* It IS. *FROM meeting ) **x*** - maybe you skipped it?

Comment: Ah. Didn't realize that was a feature. I renamed the fields as I don't want to get in trouble for copy pasting my homework directly, so I must've missed it.